# Preserving Link List order in a CQWP in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: list, sharepoint-2010, hyperlink, cqwp

Is there a way of preserving the order of a List of Links in a CQWP in Sharepoint 2010?

I have:

- Created a List of Links
- Ordered this List using the 'Change Item Order' ribbon button
- Created a CQWP
- Added the CQWP to a page and pointed it at the List of Links
- Edited the xsl that the CQWP is using to display the Links (nothing to do with ordering at all, purely html to get the links doing what they should).

The page renders fine with the Links, but they are in the order that they were created, not their new order.

I have also tried adding the 'Order' column into the CQWP manually (in the 'CommonViewFields' property) and then tried setting the 'SortBy' property to be this 'Order'. But this doesn't preserve the order either.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have followed your steps and successfully able to get the links in the order i have decided for the items

there should be something wrong in the xsl you have modified